# ScriptableObject values not resetting after spawning the next enemy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I hope everyone is doing good.

Im doing a small personal project that have 3 enemy types so im using a ScriptableObject to save the data of each of the 3 enemy types, this is working so far but the problem is that when I hit play the enemy hp values doesn't reset after the enemy is killed.

Example:

WhiteEnemy has 7 hp, so it takes 7 hits to kill it, when another WhiteEnemy spawns I can one shot it because the hp is now set to 0 since 7 - 7 = 0.

Hope I explained in a good way.

I haven't tried a lot since im kinda lost and im just a beginner in game development, I understand how the script works but I just dont know how to reset the values each time an enemy spawns.

Comment: Sounds like they should instantiate their own copy of the health object, to deepcopy it. Be default reference types like scriptable objects are copied by reference, so each instance of your enemy is going to be refereing to the exact same object, and each one will modify this shared object.

Comment: They are all referencing the same instance of this ScriptableObject. You need each enemy to either create its own copy of the ScriptableObject, or only store static values in the ScriptableObject and add fields like current health to your enemy class.

Comment: And how could I do this?